# Rendering Google Terrain in QGIS Layout Manager

Tags: google-maps, qgis-3, xyz-tiles, rendering, layout-manager

I am using the Google Terrain map (via XYZ Tiles).

This seems to make the system very slow, and when making a `.jpeg` through the Layout Manager, the Google Terrain will not display (render) when zooming in.

I am using QGIS 3.4.2-Madeira. Can anyone suggest something to resolve this issue?